# Updating value in a JSON file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, cypress

I am using Cypress as an automation tool. Cypress uses JavaScript. We have some config files which we want to update at runtime before running automation scripts. It's because different users can use different parameters while running the automation scripts from CI/CD tool.

I want to create a JavaScript file using which user can update these configuration files from a command prompt.

Example:

Config file: `reporter-config.json`

```
{

    "reporterEnabled": "cypress-junit,mochawesome,testrail-mocha-reporter",

    "testrailMochaReporterReporterOptions": {
        "domain":"xxxx.testrail.io",
        "username":"email",
        "password":"pass",
        "projectId":1,
        "planId":17,

}
}
```

We want to update the username and password at the run time. The expectation is to provide the JSON file name and the value we want to update for the key to the JS file. It should do the required update.

What I tried:

```
const fs = require("fs"); 
var myArgs = process.argv.slice(2); 
console.log(myArgs[0]+ " - "+myArgs[1] + " - "+myArgs[2] );

var filename = myArgs[0];
var updatedUsername = myArgs[1];
var updatedPassword= myArgs[2];


// Read data.json file 
fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) { 

    // Check for errors 
    if (err) throw err; 

    // Converting to JSON 
    const users = JSON.parse(data); 

    console.log(users); // Print users  

    users.testrailMochaReporterReporterOptions.username = updatedUsername;
    users.testrailMochaReporterReporterOptions.password = updatedPassword;


    // STEP 3: Writing to a file 
    fs.writeFile(filename, JSON.stringify(users), err => { 

    // Checking for errors 
    if (err) throw err;  

    console.log("Done writing"); // Success 
    }); 

});
```

command I pass: node update-data.js "reporter-config.json" "username" "password"

It successfully updates the username and password value.But I need to always provide username and password value both from the command line.

But my requirement is  if I provide username="newusername" or password="newpassword"  it should search for username and password key and update the respective value. So I need not worry whether user provided one argument or two.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe. I have updated what I have tried also what exactly I want. Would you be able to help?

Comment: It seems like you're asking about handling the command line arguments better, in which case see e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs